# Отразить персонажа в другую сторону Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Работаю в Unity с 2D персонажем.

При отзеркаливании в другую сторону тело персонажа смещается в другую сторону по оси X.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

   public float speed;
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Vector2 moveVelocity;
   private Animator anim;
   private float moveInp;
   private bool facingRight = true;
  void Start()
   {
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      
   }

   void Update()
   {
       moveInp = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
      moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
   }

   void FixedUpdate()
    {
      rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    if(moveInp == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
    }
    else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }

    if (facingRight == false && moveInp > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight == true && moveInp < 0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
    }

   void Flip()
   {
       facingRight = !facingRight;
       Vector2 Scaler = transform.localScale;
       Scaler.x *= -1;
       transform.localScale = Scaler;
   }

}
```

Скриншоты:

[image: Исходное положение]
[image: Нажата стрелочка влево]

Comment: `При отзеркаливании в другую сторону тело персонажа смещается в другую сторону` переформулируйте проблему, пока непонятно, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/l5AUstT загрузил 2 скриншота проблемы

Comment: Вставьте их прямо в пост.

Comment: Прошу прощения за столь большую задержку, загрузил

Comment: Ничего страшного, я вам все равно не помощник, Unity не знаю. Просто помог оформить вопрос.

Comment: И на том спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, дело было в положении, оно должно быть установлено на 0 по оси X, у меня же было отрицательное значение.